# Javascript regex.test() return different result on the same data

Tags: javascript, regex

My regexp

```
var EMAIL_REGEXP = /^[\w.+\-!?/:#$%&*();|<>]{3,}@[a-z0-9]+\.[a-z0-9]+(\.?[a-z0-9]+)*$/g;
```

But when i test in console on some text like `"mail@mail.ru"` it return true for first `test()` call and false for second `test()` call.
I think that is en browser error? but nodejs work the same.
How can i fix it and why it is happening?

Comment: @Wiktor I understand the reason you marked this as duplicate, but the thing is op is passing a single email address to a function test(str) which performs the regex operation... so in this case, without seeing his method body not sure whether the global flag is the problem or not

Comment: @Maverick_Mrt: JS tag, `/g` in the regex, *it return true for first test() call and false for second test() call* - we  have all the evidence of what is going on.

Comment: the reason is a global flag, i have changed it and script work correct

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Andrew I knew it could have been the reason, but see as you were talking about a test method therefore it could have been possible with global flag too : https://jsfiddle.net/euwdo8c7/2/ as long as the variables are local